# CXF post api fails via jmeter

Tags: post, jmeter, cxf

Trying to automate my test cases using jmeter. I have used cxf for rest apis on my web server. I have an api which actually takes a java object as parameter. On jmeter I have selected the POST method under HTTP-request and sending json data in Body data. The api gets called fine. However the parameter comes null and hence by api fails. I did try changing the parameter to String object, however I get this string as null.

Is this the right way to call apis via jmeter. Or is this failing because I have used cxf on my server.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) for detailed explanation on JMeter configuration for REST API testing.

---

Other thing you could try out is using [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/) tool to send the request to your CXF endpoint and if it succeeds - inspect the request and configure JMeter accordingly. By the way, SoapUI has some [limited load testing capabilities](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/load-testing.html), may be it will be enough for your scenario

Comment: I have tried adding the manager and setting the value to application/json already but no luck